# Spring Boot with jersey and usage of Hateaos

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, hateoas

I have been going through many tutorials and searching web sometime now. But i haven't been able to get a correct website where i get an example of HATEOAS being implemented in a Spring Boot with Jersey as starter project.

can any one please guide me here.

We have below in pom.xml

```
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath />
        </parent>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- only dependency needed -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
                <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
            </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

So in my application controller i would be using @Path to configure api end points. I am unable to use Hateoas library as is as they explain and be best suitable with Spring Rest and not Jersey.

So could someone please point me in right direction, I want to embed hypermedia into my rest response. Which is the best standard? HAL or any other? Which library supports them ? please help

Comment: What part are you having problems with? Asking us for how to _use it_ is too broad, as that implies you want a tutorial for all use cases. Please ask a specific question to a specific problem.

Comment: @Paul Is Jersey with HATEOAS a feasible option for HAL standards?